# Magento 1.9 - What is the best way to edit core files?

Tags: core, edit, magento1.9.2.3, local

I need to edit:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml

editing core files is dangerous, may I know how can I edit without affect core files.

eg: Some case we can edit the file

> app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template

instead of edit core path

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template

. Same how to follow in `app/design/adminhtml`?

Answer (score 1):

Magento - Override adminhtml template file
add below code to config.xml file of extension (you created)

```
   <stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <default>default</default>
                <template>rwd</template>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Now create rwd folder under adminhtml/default/rwd package.
and create template and layout file as you want to override.

like we want to override order items.phtml file.

```
<root>/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml
<root>/app/design/adminhtml/default/rwd/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml
```

Comment: Error, i want to edit the file -> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items.phtml, so that i have moved the file  -> app\design\adminhtml\default\rwd\template\sales\order\view\items.phtml my correction not applied. @Rakesh Donga

Answer (score 1):

Please create small module for new theme

`app/code/local/[Vendorname]/[MyAdminTheme]/etc/config.xml`
`

    
        
            1.0.0

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>newadmintheme</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

`app/etc/modules/[Vendorname]_[MyAdminTheme].xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendorname_MyAdminTheme>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vendorname_MyAdminTheme>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Copy `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml` to new location
`app/design/adminhtml/default/newadmintheme/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml` then edit it.